# Elegir un elemento de Array aleatoriamente

Tags: php, array

Dispongo de un array con los elementos:

```
$base = array(
            'root',
            'user',
            'admin',
            'hack',
            'cloud',
            'apple',
            'linux',
            'blue',
            'dark',
            'pink',
            'free',
            'chard',
            'ligth',
            'moon',
            'teen'
);
```

Deseo seleccionar uno de los elementos al azar.

Y tengo dos alternativas. Esta:

```
$item = $base[rand(0,count($base)-1)]
```

Y esta:

```
$item = array_rand(array_flip($base),1);
```

¿Es alguna de las dos más eficiente que la otra? ¿Cómo se diferencian?

Answer (score 2):

Hice unas pruebas en el navegador con la librería [pTester](https://bitbucket.org/Orici/tools__ptester/src/master/):

```
<?php

require 'pTester/ptester.php';
use ironwoods\tools\ptester\PTester;


function test_one(array $base): void
{
    $x = $base[rand(0, count($base)-1)];
}

function test_two(array $base): void
{
    $x = array_rand(array_flip($base), 1);
}


/**
 * Tests
 *
 */

$base = [
    'root',
    'user',
    'admin',
    'hack',
    'cloud',
    'apple',
    'linux',
    'blue',
    'dark',
    'pink',
    'free',
    'chard',
    'ligth',
    'moon',
    'teen',
];

$arr_with_tests = [
    test_one($base),
    test_two($base),
];

PTester::setNumberOfRunningTests(2000);
PTester::setRunningCycles(TRUE);
PTester::test($arr_with_tests);
```

Si repites varias veces:

```
Tested method number: 1
Used time: 7.65061378479E-8 miliseconds
Used memory: 0 bytes.

Tested method number: 2
Used time: 7.8002333641052E-8 miliseconds
Used memory: 0 bytes.


Tested method number: 1
Used time: 7.4004173278809E-8 miliseconds
Used memory: 0 bytes.

Tested method number: 2
Used time: 7.5004696846008E-8 miliseconds
Used memory: 0 bytes.


Tested method number: 1
Used time: 7.7004194259644E-8 miliseconds
Used memory: 0 bytes.

Tested method number: 2
Used time: 8.3004355430603E-8 miliseconds
Used memory: 0 bytes.
```

Si estoy interpretando correctamente el resultado **parece que el primer método es algo más lento**.

#### Plus: usa mt_rand() en lugar de rand()

Se recomienda el uso de `mt_rand()` que es más rápido que `rand()`, además parece que `rand()` tiene otros problemas y es reemplazado por completo en las últimas versiones de PHP. Consulta este [hilo acerca de las diferencias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760650).

Si ***repetimos las pruebas, usando mt_rand() en lugar de rand()*** tendríamos:

```
Tested method number: 1
Used time: 8.1004023551941E-8 miliseconds
Used memory: 0 bytes.

Tested method number: 2
Used time: 7.700502872467E-8 miliseconds
Used memory: 0 bytes.


Tested method number: 1
Used time: 6.9506883621216E-8 miliseconds
Used memory: 0 bytes.

Tested method number: 2
Used time: 8.0002188682556E-8 miliseconds
Used memory: 0 bytes.


Tested method number: 1
Used time: 7.7004432678223E-8 miliseconds
Used memory: 0 bytes.

Tested method number: 2
Used time: 8.2505106925964E-8 miliseconds
Used memory: 0 bytes.
```

Answer (score 0):

Con la segunda forma trabajas mas para obtener el valor aleatorio. Primero haces un array_flip, que obliga a PHP a trabajar sobre todos los elementos del array, y luego haces un array_rand que de nuevo le hace trabajar sobre el array completo.

La primera forma sin embargo obtiene el valor aleatorio a través de la creación de un índice aleatorio, que es un valor mucho más "liviano" de obtener y luego solo se "ataca" directamente sobre este valor. (primero se evalua la longitud del array, pero esto de nuevo es algo muy rapido y barato de hacer para PHP).

No obstante, hablar de la eficiencia de estas funciones sólo tiene sentido si las invocas un númreo de veces alto. En cualquier otro sentido, no notarás diferencia alguna (a no ser que el array de entrada sea algo muy grande, en cuyo caso la primera de las formas se hará más patente como la mejor manera).

Lo que puedes hacer para optimizar ligeramente tu consulta es en lugar de obtener bajo cada iteración la longitud del array, al ser siempre la misma, es hacer unicamente la evaluación una vez:

```
$n = count($base); //hazlo fuera y así cada vez que iteres para obtener un aleatorio, no tienes que invocar la funcion una y otra vez.

$rand = mt_rand(0,$n-1);
$item = $base[$rand];
```

Es también una buena idea que cambies la funcion rand por mt_rand